# class constructor is giving me an error

Tags: java

My current code isn't complete however **what I am trying to do is get my method `readDataFromFile` to read files containing animals (name, species etc) and add them to my `Zoo` using scanner.**

I have **2** classes: **`Zoo` & `Animal`**

> **I have an error with this line: `addAnimal( new Animal(species, name) );`**

Blue Jay gives me this explanation as to why it doesn't work:

> "constructor Animal in Animal class cannot be applied to given types;
>
> required: Java.lang.String,java.lang.String,MyZoo found:
>   java.lang.String,java.lang.String reason: actual and formal argument
>   lists differ in length"

**Zoo Class:**

```
public class MyZoo

{
    private String zooId;
    private int nextAnimalIdNumber;
    private TreeMap<String, Animal> animals;
    private Animal animal;

    public MyZoo(String zooId)
    {
        this.zooId = zooId.trim().substring(0,3).toUpperCase();
        nextAnimalIdNumber = 0;
        animals = new TreeMap<String, Animal>();
    }

    public void addAnimal(Animal animal)
    {
        animals.put(animal.getName(), animal);
        this.animal = animal;
    }


    public void readDataFromFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException
    {  

        JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame();
        FileDialog fileDialogBox = new FileDialog(mainWindow, "Open", FileDialog.LOAD);
        fileDialogBox.setDirectory("."); 
        fileDialogBox.setVisible(true);

        fileName = fileDialogBox.getFile();
        String directoryPath = fileDialogBox.getDirectory();

        File dataFile = new File (fileName);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(dataFile);
        zooId = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("ID of the Zoo: " + zooId);
        int noOfAnimalsRead = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("no of animals read from file was " + noOfAnimalsRead + "\n");
        scanner.nextLine();
        while( scanner.hasNext() )
        {
            String name = scanner.next();
            System.out.println("Name of Animal: " + name);
            String species = scanner.next();
            System.out.println("Name of species: " + species);
            String id = scanner.next();
            System.out.println("ID of Animal: " + id);

            addAnimal( new Animal(species, name) );        
            scanner.nextLine() ;
        }
        scanner.close();
    }

}
```

Animal Class:

```
public class Animal
{
    private String id;
    private String species;
    private String name;
    public Animal(String species, String name, MyZoo owner)
    {
        id = owner.allocateId();
        this.species = species;
        this.name  = name;
    }

    public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public String getSpecies()
    {
        return species;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return id + "  " + name + ": a " + species;
    }
}
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem? Are you getting an error? an exception? Simply stating 'this doesn't work' will not get you ANY help.

Comment: Ahh. What i have created so far compiles without error, however im struggling to create a loop to read data from files. Any guidance would be cool

Comment: In fact i (UPDATED) another line to my while loop inside my readDateFromFile method and this line comes up with an error: addAnimal( new Animal(species, name) );

Comment: maybe you should post the error?

Comment: Updated my post with the error.

Comment: no ... post what the actual error is. what is the error you get back from the output?

Comment: post your implementation of the Animal class

Comment: I have posted my animal class.

Answer (score 1):

This is a constructor issue not a Scanner issue.

Your Animal constructor has 3 arguments. That means in the while loop, when you make a new Animal, you need to provide 3 arguments! The only way around this is to overload your constructor (add a new one that takes two arguments). Add this to your Animal class:

```
public Animal(String species, String name)
{
    this.species = species;
    this.name  = name;
}
```

Comment: So would it be possible at all to do this without touching the Animal Class?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the "explanation" from the IDE, it seems you aren't passing enough arguments into the constructor when you create the new Animal object. It is expecting an object of type myZoo on top of the species as a String and name as a String.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor of your `Animal` class needs three arguments (`String species, String name, MyZoo owner`) and you are calling it with only two: `new Animal(species, name)`. Either provide the `MyZoo` `Object` or add a new constructor:

```
public Animal(String species, String name){
  this.species = species;
  this.name  = name;
}
```

Since you only need the `id` of the `MyZoo` object, you could change the `Animal` constructor to this:

```
 public Animal(String species, String name, int zooId){
   this.id = zooId;
  this.species = species;
  this.name  = name;
}
```

You can then instantiate `Animal` like this:

```
 Animal animal = new Animal(species, name, zooId);
```

For your `MyZoo` class, you could do this for adding an `Animal`:

```
 addAnimal( new Animal(species, name, zooId) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
addAnimal( new Animal(species, name) );
```

to this:

```
addAnimal( new Animal(species, name, this) );
```

The reason this works is because your `Animal` constructor needs a third parameter which is the owning zoo. Since the method containing this code is in a `Zoo` instance, you can use `this` to refer to it.

**Edit:** The added benefit is that you don't have to edit the Animal class.